# why when I do @user.email it returns null, but @user[:email] works well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a ruby beginner, here is my code:

```
@user = User.find_by_username('myname', :select => 'users.email')
email = @user.email
```

Why the variable "email" returns null value? But when I use the following code, it returns the right result.

```
email = @user[:email]
```

BTW, even I removed the :select, the problem is still there, that's so weird.

The object seems have no problem, here is the result when I use `@user.to_yaml`

```
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  email: xxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: Maybe you have User#email overridden (probably to return a default value when no email is set) ?

Comment: @doesterr I was about to say the same +1

Comment: Could you show us what does `@user.inspect` returns?

Comment: it will not be different from `@user.to_yaml`

Comment: @doesterr exactly! I finally found I was added email to the attr_accessor, after removing it, it works again! Thank you all!

Comment: @doesterr Make it an answer!

Comment: made an answer. this really was bugging me, glad that it's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried several things (overriding the `email` method, removing it from `attr_accessible`, removing the email column from `schema.rb`), but it always kept working.

We found the answer through the comments on the question, and `attr_accessor` was the problem.

To sum this up: never use `attr_accessor` for your `Model` attributes!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're selecting just a part of the object with `:select => 'users.email'` and it's getting converted into some special almost-model.  Try doing just this:

```
@user = User.find_by_username('myname')
email = @user.email
```

Also, what version of Rails are you using?  I ran your statements in a Rails 3.2.8 project and `@user.email` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should write your request in that way:

```
@user = User.select(:email).find_by_username('myname')
email = @user.email
```

That's the usual way to form queries with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, looking at your example I would say it's because you specify a select.

And my guess in why the [] and not the method accessor is because using a select it can retrieve values not defined for the model, like a count of some aggregation, so I suppose if using select in some cases the accessor methods doesn't get defined? But yeah, it is odd!

Comment: but when I remove the :select option, the result is still null.